# import doesn't work on class inside of a directory on swift project

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I created some folders and added into my project, then I created classes inside of them, when I try to use *import* on the pod classes like **import Firebase** the import doesn't working, but if I use the same code line in a class on the root path the *import* works ok?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you make some folders when you dont what it could do in your project...let cocoapods do their work, they are definetely much better at it than you are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, when you add the test targets into your .swift files the file doesn't see any library of the pods.